# Constructor of a derived class (Java)

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, constructor

I'm very new in Java, and about to ask a fundamental question. Hope you guys could help me. Supposed I have a base classe Super and a derived class Sub, which inheritances from class Super as follows:

```
public class TestSuperSub {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Super ou = new Sub(5,10);
  }
}

class Super {
  Super() {
    System.out.println("Super()");
  }

  Super(int x, int y) {
    System.out.println("Super(int, int)");
  }
}

class Sub extends Super {
   public Sub(int x, int y) {
      System.out.println("Sub(int, int)");
   }
}
```

The output is

```
Super()
Sub(int, int)
```

I understand, that ou calls Sub::Sub(int,int) and therefore, Sub(int, int) is printed. But why is Super() printed, since Super::Super() hasn't never been called?

Could someone please explain it to me. 
Thanks a lot!
Cheers

Comment: If this question is solved please choose an answer to mark as accepted (green checkmark), you may also upvote helpful answers.

Answer (score 1):

By default, Java will call the no-arg constructor of a super class **unless you explicitly call another constructor**. If you want to call `Super(int, int)`, you must call it explicitly:

```
public Sub(int x, int y) {
  super(x, y);
  System.out.println("Sub(int, int)");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you instantiate a class, all the superclass hierarchy must also be instantiated and it will be done so through the null constructors automatically available for each class.

The following code

```
public class Superclassing {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new C();
    }

    Superclassing() {   System.out.println("super");    }
}

class A extends Superclassing {

    A() {   System.out.println("A");    }
}

class B extends A {

    B() {   System.out.println("B");    }
}

class C extends B {

    C() {   System.out.println("C");    }
}
```

outputs

```
super
A
B
C
```

It is done so by design as mentioned in Skeet's answer and also here (oddly, it is mentioned before it is explained in 8.8.7):

[JLS 8.8.3. Constructor Modifiers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.3)

> The lack of *native* constructors is an arbitrary language design choice
>   that makes it easy for an implementation of the Java Virtual Machine
>   to verify that **superclass constructors are always properly invoked
>   during object creation**.

(emphasis mine.)

Answer (score 0):

> But why is Super() printed, since Super::Super() hasn't never been called?

It has, because your `Sub` constructor is *implicitly* calling it. It's as if you'd written:

```
public Sub(int x, int y) {
   super();
   System.out.println("Sub(int, int)");
}
```

From [section 8.8.7 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.7):

> The first statement of a constructor body may be an explicit invocation of another constructor of the same class or of the direct superclass (§8.8.7.1).
>
> ...
>
> It is a compile-time error for a constructor to directly or indirectly invoke itself through a series of one or more explicit constructor invocations involving this.
>
> If a constructor body does not begin with an explicit constructor invocation and the constructor being declared is not part of the primordial class Object, then the constructor body implicitly begins with a superclass constructor invocation "`super();`", an invocation of the constructor of its direct superclass that takes no arguments.

If you want to call a different superclass constructor, you need to do that implicitly. When you call a subclass constructor, that will *always* work its way up through the inheritance hierarchy, executing the body of the superclass constructor before the subclass constructor... indeed, even field initializers in the subclass are only run after the superclass constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Its the very basic fundamental concept in Java. Its the **magic** of **super** keyword and **constructor chaining**.

Go through these links. Hope this would help you understand the concept.

http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jnut/ch03_04.htm

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html

Answer (score 0):

By Default in constructor of sub class
the first line is call base class default constructor (implicitly) if no constructor is mentioned that is **

> super();

**
if you write

> super(x,y);

then other constructor will be called

**Note : First line of constructor is to call base class constructor.
if there is no super class then *Object*  class's constructor is called**

Answer (score 0):

```
class A{
A(){
    System.out.println("no-arg constructor in A");
}

A(int a){
    System.out.println("parameterized constructor in A");
}
}

class B extends A{
B(){

    System.out.println("no-arg constructor in B");
}

B(int b){
            //by default during compilation super() keyword will be added in first line of this constructor
    System.out.println("paramterized constructor in B");
}

}
public class TestDemo {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    B aVar = new B(10); 
    aVar = new B();

}

}

Output:
  // output for first object i.e, new B(10)
   no-arg constructor in A
   paramterized constructor in B
  //output for second object i.e, new B()
   no-arg constructor in A
   no-arg constructor in B
```

**A super() keyword will be add by default by the compiler during compilation depending on the Object that u create in main method.**